# How do I fix "Error executing task CreateAdditionalLibraryResourceCache" in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to build an app in Xamarin Studio that is synced with my Windows computer using iCloud Drive and I am getting this error when I try and build:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
Error: Error executing task CreateAdditionalLibraryResourceCache: 
Directory '/Users/edward/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/apps/Xamarin/Android/SkimurSkimmer/SkimurSkimmer/C:\Users\Edward\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\20.0.0\content\support\v7\appcompat' not found. (SkimurSkimmer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...SkimurSkimmer/mmer/SkimurSkimmer/C:\Users\Edward\AppData....

The appending of the `Windows` path onto the `OS-X` path is an issue with the files that you are syncing.

- Delete the `bin` and `obj` output directories in the project subdirectory:

  ** Actually within all your projects of the solution.
- In Xamarin Studio do a `Build All`.

At that point, the cache directory will be created if it does not already exist and the required resource will be downloaded and inflated.

You have to watch out for sync'ing those output directories, especially the `obj`.

The other to watch out for is the datetime stamp issues, as differences between the machines can cause things not to get rebuilt when needed. Again deleting the `obj` and `bin` directories solve it

Answer (score 1):

Hi I also got the error: “Error executing task CreateAdditionalLibraryResourceCache”, and my problem turned out to be a form of PathTooLongException. So, to fix this particular error, all you have to do is move the project to some other shorter directory such as "C:\", that is, if you're working in Windows. Btw I'm working in Visual Studio 2015.